# Apply subset to list of dataframes in R

Tags: r

I have a 9 dataframes with the same column names and from each I need to remove all the rows that have a "+" in the column named "Reverse".

for a single dataframe I would do it this way:

```r
df1 <- subset(df1, Reverse !=  "+")
```

is there a way to do this with all 9 at the same time?

I tried to put them all in a list first and then just use the same code as above but it doesnt work:

```r
df.list <- list(df1, df2, df3, .....)
df.list <- subset(df.list, Reverse !=  "+")
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, use `lapply` to iterate a function on each frame:

```r
df.list <- lapply(df.list, function(dat) subset(dat, Reverse != "+"))
```

FYI, especially considering they are all the same basic structure (names, etc), then keeping them in a list makes a [lot of sense](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358227) and I encourage you to stick with `df.list` instead of individual `df1`, `df2`, etc.